# Installing ngx-translate vs buiding your own translation module

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

I would like someone to explain what are the perks of having ngx-translate over building your own translation service. The reason I'm asking this is, for now, I don't see the difficulty of building a translate pipe, which from the top of my head would consist of:

- A JSON file or an exported constant with my translations.
- A service that imports that file and has a method to translate a given string (if found in the object).
- A pipe that uses that service (for template usage).

Of course, using ngx-translate would save me some time, but considering the basic requirements of my app, I think it's a fair trade off.

Also, wouldn't my own minimal translate module reduce the size of my app a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to number of discussions we had about various 3rd party modules, whether to use them or no. This is my conclusion about it:

PROS

- 3rd library has a support (if you pick a right one), community and you can find solutions online
- its possible to find someone who's familiar with 3rd party library, you'll never find a new employee familiar with your custom solution
- for VS Code there are some neat extensions to help you work with translations
- and you're not reinventing a wheel

CONS

- you bundle size might grow, but not necessarily
- dependencies hell :/
- chose a wrong library and when it loses a support, you might be forced to refactor